# Repartitioning existing table online

Tags: postgresql, transactions, plpgsql, partitioning, data-migration

### Table schema

I have a partitioned table 'solutions' partitioned by day as follows:

solutions:

- solutions_20230115
- solutions_20230116
- solutions_20230117

  ...
- solutions_20230314
- solutions_20230315
- solutions_legacy

New partition 'solutuons_yyyymmdd' is created every day for new data.
Partition 'solutions_legacy' stores old data for the period before table 'solutions' was partitioned, currently from MINVALUE to '2023-01-15'.

### My goal

I have to create new partitions for the old data and migrate the data from partition 'solutions_legacy' to newly created partitions.

### My difficulties

The problem is I have to do it online so that table 'solutions' (at least it's recent partitions) was available for the end users while the data are being migrated.

### My solution

The idea is to detach 'solutions_legacy' from 'solutions' and work with it as a separate table while 'solutions' is available for end users. So here is my approach:

- detach 'solutions_legacy'
- create new table 'solutions_yyyymmdd'
- migrate corresponding data from 'solutuons_legacy' to 'solutions_yyyymmdd'
- attach both tables as partitions to 'solutions'

This way I suppose to have some downtime only on the first step while detaching 'solutions_legacy'.

### My code

```
create or replace PROCEDURE attach_partition(p_name text, p_start date default '2020-01-01', p_end date default '2099-01-01') 
as $$
begin
  RAISE NOTICE '%: Attaching partition ''%''...', clock_timestamp(), p_name;
  execute format(
    'ALTER TABLE solutions ATTACH PARTITION %I
    FOR VALUES FROM (%L) TO (%L)', p_name, p_start, p_end);
  RAISE NOTICE '% ''%'' has been attached', clock_timestamp(), p_name;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create or replace PROCEDURE detach_partition(p_name text)
as $$
begin
  RAISE NOTICE '%: Detaching ''%''...', clock_timestamp(), p_name;
  execute format('ALTER TABLE solutions DETACH PARTITION %I', p_name);
  RAISE NOTICE '%: ''%'' has been detached', clock_timestamp(), p_name;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create or replace PROCEDURE create_table(p_name text, p_start date, p_end date)
as $$
begin
  RAISE NOTICE '%: Creating new table ''%'' for values from % to %...', clock_timestamp(), p_name, p_start, p_end;
  execute format('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I
    (LIKE solutions INCLUDING DEFAULTS)', p_name);
  RAISE NOTICE '%: Table ''%'' has been created', clock_timestamp(), p_name;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create or replace PROCEDURE migrate_data(p_name text, p_start date, p_end date)
as $$
begin
  RAISE NOTICE '%: Migrating data to ''%''...', clock_timestamp(), p_name;
  execute format('
    WITH moved_rows AS (
      DELETE FROM public.solutions_legacy sl
      WHERE created_at >= %L
        and created_at < %L
      RETURNING sl.*
    )
    INSERT INTO %I
    SELECT * FROM moved_rows', p_start, p_end, p_name);
  RAISE NOTICE '%: Data has been migrated', clock_timestamp();
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


do
$$
declare 
  new_partitions_count int := 3;
  rec record;
  partition_start date;
  partition_end   date;
  partition_name  text;
begin
  call detach_partition('solutions_legacy');
  -- !!! HERE IS WHERE I TRY TO COMMIT
  RAISE NOTICE '%: Querying ''solutions_legacy'' to determine % new partitions...', clock_timestamp(), new_partitions_count;
  for rec in 
    select distinct date_trunc('day', created_at)::date d 
    from public.solutions_legacy 
    order by d desc limit new_partitions_count
  loop
    partition_start := rec.d;
    partition_end   := rec.d + 1;
    partition_name  := 'solutions_' || TO_CHAR(partition_start, 'yyyymmdd') ;
    call create_table(partition_name, partition_start, partition_end);
    call migrate_data(partition_name, partition_start, partition_end);
    call attach_partition(partition_name, partition_start, partition_end);
  end loop;
  call attach_partition('solutions_legacy', p_end => partition_start);
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here is an example log it producers for better understanding:

```
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:28:02.306654+00: Detaching 'solutions_legacy'...
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:31:07.60235+00: 'solutions_legacy' has been detached
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:31:07.602576+00: Querying 'solutions_legacy' to determine 3 new partitions...
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:33:29.410183+00: Creating new table 'solutions_20230114' for values from 2023-01-14 to 2023-01-15...
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:33:29.416459+00: Table 'solutions_20230114' has been created
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:33:29.417196+00: Migrating data to 'solutions_20230114'...
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:36:14.731551+00: Data has been migrated
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:36:14.732235+00: Attaching partition 'solutions_20230114'...
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:37:51.100635+00 'solutions_20230114' has been attached
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:37:51.100761+00: Creating new table 'solutions_20230113' for values from 2023-01-13 to 2023-01-14...
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:37:51.102272+00: Table 'solutions_20230113' has been created
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:37:51.102315+00: Migrating data to 'solutions_20230113'...
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:40:10.749074+00: Data has been migrated
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:40:10.749182+00: Attaching partition 'solutions_20230113'...
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:41:47.559556+00 'solutions_20230113' has been attached
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:41:47.559661+00: Creating new table 'solutions_20230112' for values from 2023-01-12 to 2023-01-13...
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:41:47.561249+00: Table 'solutions_20230112' has been created
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:41:47.561291+00: Migrating data to 'solutions_20230112'...
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:44:07.43721+00: Data has been migrated
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:44:07.43729+00: Attaching partition 'solutions_20230112'...
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:45:41.37163+00 'solutions_20230112' has been attached
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:45:41.371922+00: Attaching partition 'solutions_legacy'...
NOTICE:  2023-03-15 10:47:56.991827+00 'solutions_legacy' has been attached
DO

Query returned successfully in 20 min.
```

### My problem

Even though the data is successfully migrated to newly created partitions, table 'solutions' is not available for the end users during the migration process, even SELECT queries are waiting for the Lock. I suppose that's because the whole script is a single transaction. So, I try to commit the changes right after the call to `detach_partition('solutions_legacy')` or at the very end of this procedure, yet in most cases I get the error

> ERROR: invalid transaction termination

I have tried adding COMMIT in some places as well as playing with BEGIN/END statements.

What is the right approach to this problem?

> PostgreSQL 15.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r4) 12.2.1 20220924, 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DO` blocks allow for transaction control **if and only if** you didn't wrap it inside a transaction.

I'd advise to execute the do block **outside** of a transaction, and your `commit` statement should work as planned.

EDIT: see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html#id-1.9.3.102.8 for documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, that's greatly appreciated. How exactly I don't wrap my DO into transaction?

Comment: Maybe by adding a  `commit;` statement just before the `DO` block?

Comment: It gives me **WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress** and thus does not help

Comment: I'd need the whole story to understand, but that might be because you (the tool you use?) might have started a transaction at the very beginning, wrapping the **whole** story. Either don't start a wrapping transaction (and then ignore my previous comment) OR make your tool stop sending a final `COMMIT` at the end, which I suspect is where your warning comes from (which is just a warning, this strategy should still yield shorter locks)

Comment: Sorry that I was not clear enough. I've added **COMMIT** before the **DO** block and that line has given me the WARNING "there is no transaction in progress", which means there is no wrapping transaction. The tool I use is PGADMIN. The code above is the whole story, I don't have anything else. Thank you for trying to help, I appreciate this.

Comment: WOW! PgAdmin really was the one to blame! **psql  < script.sql** solved the problem! Thank you so much for your help!